# rails : Ruby on Rails calculating “rank” of a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I have 2 tables (relationships many-to-many with sqlite3) :
-User
-Credit(with user_id & score)

And I try to compute the rank of the user.
To compute the rank of this user I need to find the SUM of all the credits of this user.
 But I don't know how do this :(

I have tried something like this but it don't work :

```
User.all.join(:credits).order(sum(:score)).index(@user)
```

I get this error :

```
TypeError in UsersController#index
can't convert Symbol into String
```

Thank !

Comment: Have you tried to do what the error message tells you and use strings instead of `:credits` and `:score`?

Comment: Well, I get this error now : ( User.all.join("credits").order(sum("score")).index(@user) )
undefined method `sum' for #<String:0xb5ce7c54>

And when I delete the sum : ( User.all.join("credits").order("score").index(@user) )
undefined method `order' for #<String:0xb5695a7c>

Comment: You want to find the rank of *a* User, or the rank of *all* users?

Comment: When you do the `.all` command, you fetch the result ... It returns an array and not a query object so you cannot use any operations like order, join, etc on them ... Put the .all to the end

Comment: You mean to do this ? : User.join(:credits).order(sum(:score)).index(@user).all ? Because this still doesn't work :(. (I get this error : undefined method `join' for #<Class:0xb5987bf4>)

Answer (score 0):

To sum (or count) you should use sum with group (that is converted in "group by"),
because you need to group the users in some way to be able to sum their score.
I did not try the following code, but it should be something like this:

```
User.select("users.name, sum(credits.score)").joins(:credits).group("credits.user_id")
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Hum, I see nothing when I do this : " User.select("users.name, sum(credits.score)").joins(:credits).group("credits.user_id").index(@user)"
And when I do this  "User.select("users.name, sum(credits.score)").joins(:credits).group("credits.user_id")" I get this error : "#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb59d74d8>"

Comment: Well, If i do this :

 User.select("users.name, sum(credits.score)").joins(:credits).group("credits.user_id").all

I get this : [#<User name: "Example User">, #<User name: "Mr. Destany Schaefer">, #<User name: "georgy">]
where example user is the first user (by id) destany is the first user by credits and georgy is our current user.

Comment: you are getting the name of the grouped users, it should appear also the score sum, try naming it:  User.select("users.name, sum(credits.score) AS rank").joins(:credits).group("credits.user_id"), and I think you don't need ".all"

Comment: Hum, I get the same error ([#<User name: "Example User">, #<User name: "Mr. Destany Schaefer">, #<User name: "georgy">] with .all at the end and <ActiveRecord::Relation without .all)

Comment: Anyone have an idea ? I'm sorry but I still search an anwser to this question :(

Comment: Don't you think that you should group by users name since you are selecting user's name as well. Your query should be something like this:

    User.select("users.name, sum(credits.score)").joins(:credits).group("credits.name")